# ezSQL cache

Tags: caching

the ezSQL is nice script to use , but for some reason when you update db and run script again , it does not update the cache .

any advise ?

tks

Answer (score 2):

Can ou be more specific as to what cache you mean?

The ezSQL disk chache? 
The ezSQL query cache on a per script run basis?

If you are talking about the disk cache, there is a setting in ezSQL that allows you to specify the how long the cache lasts before refreshing the cache files.

ezSQLcore->cache_timeout = 24; // hours by default

So disk cache files will not be re-cached until 24 hours has passed.

Answer (score -2):

Not getting much action here. Try ez's [forums](http://www.jvmultimedia.com/portal/?q=forum).